# Countdown until matching digits in coral

Tags: google-coral

How do I do a countdown until matching digits in coral? What I'm trying to do is write a program that takes the input number (as long as it's between 20 and 98) and it counts down by 1 until the digits are the same. For example if the input number is 93, the output will be 93 92 91 90 89 88. Once the count gets to 88 (the two digits are the same) the program stops. Or if the input is 77 then the output will only be 77.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is related to google-coral, but here is a suggestion. You can start by writing a `compare_digit` function that takes in a number, convert it to a string and compare the 2 characters in that string. Then in the main loop, just print out the number, call `compare_digit` on that number and then minus one from that number. Here is some pseudo code for you:

```
def compare_digits(num):
    string num_str = to_string(num)
    return num_str[0] == num_str[1]

def main():
    input_num = input("Enter number")
    while(True):
        if compare_digits(input_num):
            stop_program()
        print(input_num)
        input_num--
```